# Why are workspace tabs different when opening legacy (pre-2.80) files?

Tags: interface, versions

Several years ago I did a lot of work with Blender pre-version 2.80. As I'm reacquainting myself with Blender 2.93.5 there are some differences that I can't figure out. For example, when I open a legacy Blender file the top workspace tabs are different from a new empty file.

[image: Example]

Why aren't the workspace tabs consistent between older and newer files?

For example, a new blank file defaults to *Layout*, but a legacy file defaults to *Default*; are they the same thing?

Or, a new blank file has a *Shading* option in the top menu bar, but there's none in the legacy file. Why is that?

Answer (score 3):

This is because information about UI *workspace* settings are kept in the file.

When you open a Blender file by using the open command from the Menu, the sidebar is hidden by default, but if you open it (Shortcut <kbd>N</kbd> or left mouse drag the arrow at the left edge) you get this:

[image: open file menu showing sidebar not hidden]

As you can see there is a checkbox for *Load UI* and the default is enabled, meaning that the UI elements saved in the file are loaded with the file.  The default is to enable loading, so that any customizations you've made to the UI layout and saved will be available when you next open the file.

If you uncheck this, Blender won't load the UI elements, obviously, and you will get the workspaces from the version you're running.

Once you save the file from the running version, the default will be to load the UI elements that are stored with it.

Comment: Yay! Thank you Marty Fouts. I was pulling my hair out trying to find my way back into the materials node editor and this is a HUGE step in the right direction. I also see there are tutorial videos addressing the change to 2.80, so I've got some homework. Much appreciated! :)

Comment: 2.8x is a major change from 2.79.  2.9x is a pretty big change from 2.8.  If you want to take it in steps go to 2.83LTS first and then from there to 2.93.5LTS second.  If you want to skip he 2.8x learning, Going to 2.93 directly is a bit rough but might be faster.

Comment: Thank you for the tip. I think I'll keep fumbling around 2.93 until I find my way back to being productive again. Again, much appreciated.